# How to get dom element by attribute with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page where I have a table and a grid, and when I click on row from the grid:

```
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
        $scope.formula = row.entity.formula;
        console.log(row.entity.factId);
    });
```

I want a certain cell from the table to be highlighted.

based on the factid attribute.

```
<div factid="1010898">320.00</div>
```

What is the best angular way without using any external library like jquery, jqlite from angular being ok to use.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use jqlite $('[attr=val]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can do with jqlite:

```
angular.element('[factid=1010898]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with:

```
$('#report-content').find('[factid = ' + row.entity.factId + ']');
```

where "report-content" is the id of the container.